# Concat two observables for firestore query on multiple fields

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, observable, angularfire

I am trying to get a user search functionality working in my AngularFire app.
As firestore doesn't support these queries I thought it would be enough to query the fields separately

```
getUsersByName(searchValue: string) {
    const firstNames = this.afs.collection<IUser>('user', ref => ref.orderBy('firstname').startAt(searchValue).endAt(searchValue+'\uf8ff')).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    const lastNames = this.afs.collection<IUser>('user', ref => ref.orderBy('lastname').startAt(searchValue).endAt(searchValue+'\uf8ff')).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    return concat(firstNames, lastNames);
  }
```

This only works for the `firstNames` though. Only the first Observable is being used. I think I don't understand the concat operator but it's not clear to me according the docs what the current best solution would be for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you could use zip operator

```
const firstNames: Observable<string>
const lastNames: Observable<string>
zip(firstNames,lastNames).subscribe(
  ([firstName,lastName]) => { console.log(firstName,lastName);}
)
```

if firstNames and lastNames emit only one item, combineLatest([firstNames,lastNames]) will be more readable

great link to learn how to use these operators https://indepth.dev/posts/1114/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams

Comment: Thank you for the usefull link. Changing my return to `return zip(firstNames, lastNames);`didn't work though, I didn't get any result

Answer (score 0):

The reason this only works for first name is because of how `concat` works; it will only use one observable at a time until it completes, but the firestore observables are long lived and will not complete.

You should use `merge` instead of `concat`.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

getUsersByName(searchValue: string) {
    const firstNames = this.afs.collection<IUser>('user', ref => ref.orderBy('firstname').startAt(searchValue).endAt(searchValue+'\uf8ff')).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    const lastNames = this.afs.collection<IUser>('user', ref => ref.orderBy('lastname').startAt(searchValue).endAt(searchValue+'\uf8ff')).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
    return merge(firstNames, lastNames);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this `return firstNames.pipe(merge(lastNames));` but with no success. I saw results in a glimpse for firstNames but after that none of my tests was returning result

Comment: You used the `merge` operator instead of the static merge function.  I've added example to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It is still behaving weird though, in the subscription I get multiple events so it seems the subscription is on both of the Observables separately while I expect this to behave as a single Observable..

Comment: Yes, that is how `merge` works, it will emit when any of the source observables emit, but to consumers of `getUsersByName()`, it is a single observable.  What is your desired output?

Comment: I wanted to have only have one emission as well for my search operation, is that possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible, but you need to be clear on 1) what triggers it and 2) what data is emitted. Currently it is triggered whenever either `firstname` or `lastname` emit.  And you are emitting either a collection for first names or collection of last names.